# Sending converted jms with camel

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Can anyone help me.  I m trying to send a message using camel.  Maybe i have the concept wrong.w
I would like to send a simple message to an activemq.  I have a messageService who was a sendmethode. The proble is i m sending a pojo as message and i would like it to be automaticly transformed to a json string.  That's why i tried using camel.

I've defined a rout who point to my send methode and added a marshaller in the rout.

The problem is that camel seems to constantly send a jms message every second.
What i would like is that camel converts my output of my message to json when i call the sendMethode.

Here is my rout:

```
<from uri="bean:messageService?method=sendMessage" />
    <marshal>
    <json library="Gson"/>
    </marshal>
<inOnly uri="activemq:com.pack.checkSynchronicityUrl" />
```

So when i call the service messageService i want camel to convert the output to json and put it on the queue.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a route the starts from a bean

```
<from uri="bean:xxx"/>
```

using the bean component, then Camel will constantly call the bean method, in an endless loop.

So you would need to do something else, for example from the java code in your bean, you can send a message to a Camel route using the producer template api, pojo producing, or use a proxy etc. See links below

- http://camel.apache.org/bean-injection.html
- http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html
- http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html
- http://camel.apache.org/spring-remoting.html
- http://camel.apache.org/pojo-messaging-example.html

Answer (score 0):

@Claus has already explained the issue with your route.

The behavior that you need can be achieved in different ways as you can see in those links. Here is a sample that can fit your purpose.

Define a route as:

```
from("direct:start").
   marshal(...).
      to("activemq:com.mele...);
```

or similar in spring dsl. The following code can be part of messageService.sendMessage() method:

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelcontext.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", myPojo);
```